# How to fix HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to work on a web app, this is my first web app.  I am getting this error:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

How do I configure the web server?  I don't even know what directory it is talking about.

the app is trying to go here: http://localhost:22025/

I tried searching but very little relevant information comes up.  I typed inetmgr into the run box but nothing came up.  so I tried installing IIS 7.5 but it said I already have a newer version installed.

I found out it is IIS express.  I also found this information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

But I cant figure out how to set this up.  I'm betting there is no exe but even if I figure out what the output file type is will this still allow me to debug in the ide?

I've been developing windows applications for over 10 years and have a solid knowledge of programming but with this I do not know where to start or even what kind of tutorial to search for.

EDIT:
https://github.com/Marvelous-Software/Challenge

EDIT2:
When I develop a .net class library I can point it to an exe and test the class.

[image]

```
AssemblyName.ClassName test;

test = new AssemblyName.ClassName();
test.SomeProperty = 1;
Console.WriteLine(test.SomeProperty); //If '1' display then the property worked
test.SomeMethod();
```

That is an example on how to test a class library in .net.  I would like to learn the web api.  How do I do this?  How do I run the code?

Comment: Did you set the default page for the web site? I think you can right-click one, say "default.aspx", in Solution Explorer and set it as the "start page" or similar.

Comment: which type of web application are you creating, web forms, mvc, web api, wcf service, asp.net core

Comment: In IIS, add the default document type to the one you have mate.

Comment: @Andrew - Someone provided my the project via Github.  How do I find the default page?

Comment: @Abhishek - It says Class library under project type

Comment: @TGarret - Can you tell me how I am to do this?

Comment: Can you provide the GitHub link, if it's a public repository, almost all .net web projects have the output type as class library

Comment: @Abhishek - OK, I've provided the link in the description.  I just need to know how to run this on my machine.  I wish to complete the challenge on my own.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After visiting the GitHub link, i can see that it's an Web API project as the controllers inside Api/Controllers inherit ApiController, and also you can see the route in WebApiConfig.cs which is

`routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`

you need to provide the controller name in route so the default route for the ping controller becomes

http://localhost:22025/api/ping

Just to explain you the reason for 403.14, as said in other answers, your application needs a default document to give a response at default route i.e. just the base path, which is ***usually*** not the case with Web Api as they are not ***generally*** designed for the end user in mind but as an endpoint for other client which will present a UI to the user, or another Api.

you can find the documentation for Web Api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/)

EDIT #1 - based on OP EDIT#2

While you can test a class library by referencing it to an exe, that is not unit testing in it's raw sense. You should be better off using a test framework like MSTest. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/)

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried http://localhost:22025/api/ping and received "Unable to connect."  I edited the original question to illustrate how a class library is tested.  I am hoping you may understand what I am looking for.  I would like to actually DO something.  If I can run the code I can learn from it.   If I can learn from it I can modify it.

Comment: @JohnMaher did the error coming after starting the web application. also i have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Forgot to start the application!  Doh!  Anyway raw IS better for learning.  I am more interested in learning right now than being 'better.'  I could be better later if I can get started.  Just having a hard time getting started.  Now I received "{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:22025/api/png'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'png'."}"  I tried http://localhost:22025/api/PingController but that did not work either.

Comment: @JohnMaher i guess you have a typo in the route just try api/ping like http://localhost:22025/api/ping

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "Default Document" configuration in your web server (IIS or IIS Express), this can be configured in many ways, each one depending of the web framework you are using. The most common ones in the microsoft ASP.NET stack are:

-WebForms: When you a have a lot of files with extension .aspx in your project, usually called Default.aspx, Index.aspx, Home.aspx. You could try something like type in your browser http://localhost:22025/**Default.aspx** or another page you want. If that works, you can configure the web.config file as it's described in this post https://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config

-ASP.NET MVC: When you have folders named **Model**, **Controllers** and **Views** where you probably have Controller named HomeController. The default convention in MVC is HomeController, Action Index as default. So typing something like http://localhost:22025/**Home** should be enough to view your site.

Once you realize which framework are you using, then search something like "Configure Default Document in xxx framework" to get more information.

As you bet, in web applications, you don't have an exe file as output, actually, you have an entire "output directory" with a main .dll in the "Bin" folder with the C# compiled content of your site; and a lot of files with extensions like .js, .css, .jpg and other "static" files just served as is.

This material should be a good starting point to create your first web application from zero.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Let me know if that helped you,
Have a nice day

Edit: In case of a WebAPI project, you don't have an user interface usually and it works exactly as @Abhishek Siddhu answered, you could try some debugging tools like Postman or Fiddler to match another http verbs in the actions. Because using the web browser you can only test Get named actions (those with HttpGet verb)

Comment: No aspx here.  Folders called API, Data, Entities and Service.  I am actually trying to modify an existing project   I've been challenged to add a restful service to retrieve zip codes.  I found documentation on what restful means, just can't figure out how to wire it up with this project.  I tried to run it and thats when I received the error.